# Displaying items from an array in Android app

Tags: java, android

My code in java takes in two int parameters as input, generate an array of numbers.Here is my code

```
public class Generator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        generate(500,7);
    }

    public static void generate(int goal, int days)
    {
        int[] list = new int[days];
        int res;
        res = goal/days;
        int sum = 0;
        int saved = res;


        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
        {
            list[i] += res;
            //sum += list[i];
            res += saved;

              if(i == list.length - 1 && list[list.length - 1] < goal)
              {
                int difference = goal - list[list.length-1];
                list[list.length-1] += difference;
              }
            System.out.println("day " + i + ": " + list[i]);

            //System.out.println(sum);

        }
    }

}
```

The result of this is

```
day 0: 71
day 1: 142
day 2: 213
day 3: 284
day 4: 355
day 5: 426
day 6: 500
```

I want to display this data to the user when they tap the generate button.

[image]
What is a good way to do this? Should I be using List/Recycle views and how should I go about using whichever one?

Comment: you can use listview using arrayadapter or recyclerview

Comment: if all you have is to display you can just use an `TextView` inside an `ScrollView` and display them. If you need to perform an action on individual tap, decorations around each item etc. go for a `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 1):

A Simple Listview will be sufficient. Simple implementation just require to calculate the number of rows required for the listview which in any case will be the number of days.
Else you can go for creation of TextViews through code instead of xml and loop the creation for the number of days. Then setText the textvies with the required content.

TextView Implementation

Create a linear layout(myLinearLayout) in your xml and set its orientation to vertical, then

```
 final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add

    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // create a new textview
        final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

        // set some properties of rowTextView or something
        rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

        // add the textview to the linearlayout
        myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

        // save a reference to the textview for later
        myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
    }
```

Comment: in this case, how many textviews would be created? Do you have a reference to this way of approaching it?

Comment: IMO the number of textviews will be the same as the number of days.

Comment: setting the linear layout to horizontal? shouldn't it be vertical in this case?